# How to use web app to share content in mobile?

Tags: android, mobile, web, protocols

I couldn't find anything on this. I read everything about protocol/content handlers but didn't seem to solve my problem at all.

I'm trying to find a way to allow an Android user (for example) to share content using a web application.

Examples:

1) Viewing a Youtube video in the native app. User selects 'share' and a bunch of icons appear. I want my web app to be there, so when user selects its icon, a URL is opened in the browser with a magic parameter passing the video URL so I can handle that.
2) Well, you get the idea now :)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*If your app can do some task and you want that message to be conveyed to all other apps, Android way of doing this is - Intent Filters (It tells the world what the app can do)
Intent - Android way of telling - Hey i want to get this job done ?*

If you build a social app that can share messages or photos with the user's friends, your app should support the ACTION_SEND intent. so users can initiate a "share" action from another app and launch your app to perform the action.

To allow other apps to start your activity, you need to add an  element in your manifest file for the corresponding  element.

If your activity handles both text and images for both the ACTION_SEND and ACTION_SENDTO intents. In this case, you must define two separate intent filters for the two actions because a ACTION_SENDTO intent must use the data Uri to specify the recipient's address using the send or sendto URI scheme. For example:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <!-- filter for sending text; accepts SENDTO action with sms URI schemes -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- filter for sending text or images; accepts SEND action and text or image data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This link has all the above mentioned details with lot more information.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: I'm talking about a web application, not a native Android app... this does not help me.